# Can SQL Injection Give Access to htaccess?

Tags: security

Just looking for some general advice, nothing specific.

I'm more of a programming hobbyist, so I know there are some holes in my understanding of a greater overall programming picture at times.  I have a few websites.  One is just a simple HTML website for a family member's business, which is my primary domain, and I have a subdomain for an educational website, which uses PHP and has a login system that uses MySQL to store the usernames and passwords.

I knew I was getting some internal server errors with my subdomains, and then the other day when I tried to access my primary domain through a search engine, I got a malicious redirect to another website.  I called my hosting service (GoDaddy) and they basically had me buy a service called Sucuri to clean up the malicious code.

Before the service began working, I did a little research and looked at the htaccess file, and there was the RewriteCond and RewriteRule, which pointed to a file called "default.php".  The default.php file got cleaned up before I could look at it, but I'm assuming that is what redirected my website.

(Sorry, long setup!)

My question is this:

Is it possible that the hackers accessed the htaccess through an SQL injection?  Looking through my username table I saw a weird one from Russia.  It was something like xxxxxx.ru, and obviously not one of my students.  I use stripslashes, stripwhitespace, and real_escapes_string to prevent injection, but really there isn't any sensitive information in my database that I thought I had to worry about.

Is it possible for a hacker to get access to htaccess and other files through an SQL injection or do you think they just got in another way?

I never thought anyone would care about my little websites...

Comment: I don't think sql injection can give you any file access directly, unless a potential attacker exploits any other particular db engine bug to gain OS privileges.. Also I could think of you having your user in the db with your password in plain text and that password being similar to your SO/sysadmin password (I hope its not your case)

Comment: No, the password isn't the same.  So I guess they got in another way.

Comment: SQL injection can indeed allow file level access with some dbms'es and under the right circumstances. The question lacks details, so the answer could only be "yes". :)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I realize the question is vague, but too many details to get into.  I'm just trying to get an idea of where the attack came from.  My suspicions are SQL injection, some sort of brute force attack to guess my password, or some sort of keylogger / virus on my PC.  To me it seems that any of these happening would be so rare, but I'm guessing my understanding of PHP / MySQL security is probably the weakest of these, so that could be the culprit.

Comment: Did you try looking at access logs?